# How to Implement nuxtServerInit Action to load data from server-side on the initial load in Pinia (Nuxt3)

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxtserverinit

**My Code:**

```js
export const useMenuStore = defineStore("menuStore", {
  state: () => ({
    menus: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    async nuxtServerInit() {
     
       const { body } = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then((response) => response.json());
       console.log(body);
       this.menus = body;
       resolve();
    },
   
  },
});
```

NuxtServerInit is not working on initial page render on nuxt js vuex module mode.Anyone know this error please help me.

Comment: Specify "not working"

Answer (score 3):

In Nuxt2, the Nuxt will run the code in `nuxtServerInit()` of `store/index.js` on the server-side to boot the app.

However, in Nuxt3, there is no specific place to write the boot code, you can write the boot code anywhere instead of in `nuxtServerInit()` of `store/index.js`.

It might be helpful, especially when you need to send a request before boosting the app.

---

your pinia file may define like following:

`store/menu.js`

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useMenuStore = defineStore('menuStore', {
    state: () => ({
        _menus: [],
    }),
    getters: {
       menus() {
          return this._menus;
       }
    },
    actions: {
        async boot() {
            const { data } = await useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
            this._menus = data;
        }
    }
});
```

Then, create a plugin which named as `*.server.[ts|js]`, for example `init.server.js`

(`.sever.js` tail will let the file only run in server side)

`plugins/init.server.js`

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import { useMenuStore } from '~/store/menu.js';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
    const menu = useMenuStore(nuxtApp.$pinia);
    await menu.boot();
});
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
modules: [
    '@pinia/nuxt',
],
```

---

There is an entire [example](https://github.com/DengSihan/laravel-nuxt3-web) of SSR Nuxt3 with authorization that may help

Answer (score 1):

`NuxtServerInit` is not implemented in Pinia, but exists a workaround.

**Using Pinia alongside Vuex**

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
    ['@pinia/nuxt', { disableVuex: false }],
  ],
  // ... other options
}
```

then Include an index.js file inside /stores with a nuxtServerInit action which will be called from the server-side on the initial load.

```js
// store/index.js
import { useSessionStore } from '~/stores/session'

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ dispatch }, { req, redirect, $pinia }) {
    if (!req.url.includes('/auth/')) {
      const store = useSessionStore($pinia)

      try {
        await store.me() // load user information from the server-side before rendering on client-side
      } catch (e) {
        redirect('/auth/login') // redirects to login if user is not logged in
      }
    }
  }
}
```