# Nuxt3: provide server evaluated variable to client at every request

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am looking for a way to evaluate a variable on the server side and make it available to the client. Basically my website has a settings menu when accessed from an internal IP address. And I would like to hide that menu if the client is external / by default.

Obviously this is not secure and the routes to that settings website are protected on the server side as well as all the potential API calls that menu can make. But as an added visual I would like to hide that menu.

So every time the server serves a website to the client, I would like to check their IP address and set a `shouldShowSettings` variable to either true or false. That variable then would need to be evaluated in the menu component that's visible on every page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add some configs in your nginx conf

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Then, add a new store file in your nuxt3 project (assuming you are already using `@pinia/nuxt`).

`stores/ip.ts`

```
import {
    defineStore
} from 'pinia';

export const useIpStore = defineStore('ip', {

    state: () => ({
        _ip: ''
    }),

    getters: {
        ip: (state) => state._ip,
        isAdminIp: (state) => __YOUR_IP_WHITE_LIST_ARRAY__.includes(state._ip)
    },

    actions: {
        setIp (ip: string) {
            this._ip = ip;
        }
    }
});
```

Create a plugin in your `/plugins` (something may be like `init.ts`)

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import { useIpStore } from '~/stores/ip';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {

    const headers = useRequestHeaders();

    const ip = headers['x-real-ip'] ?? '';

    const ipStore = useIpStore();

    ipStore.setIp(ip);
});
```

---

Now, you can use it on your website, which is SSRable

```
<template>
   <aside
       v-if="shouldShowSettings"
   >
       admin only
   </aside>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

import { useIpStore } from '~/stores/ip';

const ipStore = useIpStore();

const shouldShowSettings = computed(() => ipStore.isAdminIp);

</script>
```

---

For more info about booting nuxt, [here is another answer that may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75266170/10519069)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. At first sight this seems to work but updating the value doesn't work as I'd expect. It seems that the data is cached? If I replace the code inside the plugin to a hardcoded IP and then switch back and forth between an internal and an external IP, that does not seem to always update. Often I still see the old value for a couple of minutes, even when refreshing the page in the browser including clearing the cache.

Comment: @MichaelOchs sorry to hear that. Could you please share your code? Also, do you use nuxt as your backend instead of php/java/go?

Comment: never mind, this is 100% the correct answer. I had a route that was affected by a caching policy I didn't expect! With that fixed, this works perfectly!